# Get User Location Information using EKTRON API

Tags: api, ektron

I have an ektron application and I am using the following code to get user location information,

```
            try
            {
                string IP = HttpContext.Current.Request["remote_addr"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request["ip"]))
                    IP = HttpContext.Current.Request["ip"];
                else
                    IP="my system ip";


                    //var userData = Ektron.Cms.UserContext.GetLocationInfo(IP);
                    //var userData = Ektron.Cms.UserContext.GetLocationInfo("my system ip");
                    //Ektron.Cms.UserLocationData userData = Ektron.Cms.UserContext.GetCurrentUserLocationInfo();
                   //var userData = Ektron.Cms.UserContext.GetLocationInfo(IP);


                  visitorCountry = userData.CountryCode;
            }
```

In the above code I have tried 4 different methods (these are commented by //) to get userData. But I am getting null value in all these 4 attempts that's why I'm getting exception in `userData.CountryCode;`

How can I resolve this?

In `IP` I am getting value as `::1` and `Ektron.Cms.UserContext.IP` is also giving value `::1`

I am using `ektron 8.7`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have v8.7 running right now, but I do have v9, and here's what I found:

I ran the following code:

```cs
var location = Ektron.Cms.UserContext.GetLocationInfo("74.125.225.113");

Response.Write("<pre>" + Ektron.Cms.UserContext.IP + "</pre>");
Response.Write("<pre>" + string.Format("{0}, {1} ({2} / {3})", location.City, location.Region, location.Longitude, location.Latitude) + "</pre>");
```

Here's what was displayed on the screen:

```
::1
Mountain View, CA (-122.057403564453 / 37.4192047119141)
```

I'm running the site locally on my dev machine, so I'm browsing to `http://localhost/test.aspx` - no real surprise that `Ektron.Cms.UserContext.IP` is returning "::1" for me.  I didn't have access to a server, so I pinged www.google.com and got an IP address of **74.125.225.113**.  Using that IP address, Ektron gave me a non-null response.

I thought I had v8.61 installed as well, but when I ran the same code in that environment, I got the following error:  `System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.`

I'll try to clean up my v8.6 install and see if the code works there as well, but in the meantime, I'd try using some known IP addresses and see if you get better results.